# Creating tables dynamically in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing a web application, and I have the need to create dynamically tables for each metadata the application has to refer.

Long story short, here is my thought: the table's name is always 'marker_(name of the metadata)', and I alter the created table to add each column the user needs, using data I have stored in another table, the one I'm using the cursor.

So far I've got this:

```
execute format ('
create table marker_%% (
    id_marker serial primary key
)', new.meta_name);

loop
    fetch cur_atri into name, type, size;
    exit when not found;
    execute format ('alter table marker_%% add column %% %%', new.meta_name, name, size);
end loop;
```

This is part of a trigger function after the metadata's table has been updated.

I've searched on Postgres documentation and I've seen the command 'execute format', and tried to use it, but I'm getting this error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "%" LINE 1: create table marcacao_% ( ^ QUERY: create table marcacao_% ( id_marcarcao serial primary key ) CONTEXT: PL/pgSQL function criar_tabela_colecao() line 12 at EXECUTE

I need some help with this `EXECUTE FORMAT` command

Comment: There is no `execute format` command but `execute` statement and [`format()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT). In few words: you using placeholders in wrong way. Read the mentioned documentation for more info.

Comment: I would not create tables dynamically for each new "metadata". Create a single table with an ID for "marker", columns for the information that is common to all markers and a JSONB column that contains the dynamic attributes.

Comment: "In my database I need to dynamically make" <RECORD SCRATCH> Woah... there is almost always a better way to do this.